# Maven don't run tests

Tags: java, maven

I have cucumber framework and the following pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>CucumberE2ETest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After I run my tests, I get this

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

As you can see the Tests run are 0.
The tests run fine from IntelliJ but maven does not run the tests.
My apologies for the large amount of copy-pasted content, but I want to provide as much information as possible because I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: How are your tests named ?

Comment: Hi @ArthurKlezovich , I've spend a day researching the issue. I saw the naming could be an issue. Since I am using Cucumber(Gherkin) framework they are in format Scenario:XXXX, Given:XXXX, When:XXXXX, Then:XXXX and definitions behind them are methods public void testXXXXXX(). I think the problem is with the dependencies, and most likely junit-jupiter, because the tests were running before introducing this dependency. I don't use it anymore(I think so), but I get build error, when I remove it and run "man clean install" I've got build error.

Comment: Upload your code to github and leave the link here

Answer (score 1):

You're using `cucumber-junit` which integrates with JUnit 4. However because you're using JUnit 5, Surefire will not run JUnit 4 tests. You need to add the JUnit Vintage engine or Cucumber's JUnit 5 integration.

See for a working example:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton