# @AfterAll hook in Unit is not executed

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I have the following code in Cucumber framework using Unit runner

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;

@AfterAll
public void foo(){
}

@After
public void bar(){
}
```

For some reason @After hook is executed, but @AfterAll don't want to execute.
How can I execute method after the end of all tests?

Comment: Post your code to github and paste the link here.

Comment: Read your import statements very carefully.

Comment: Hi @M.P.Korstanje, I understand my import is wrong, but don't understand what should be the correct one, since I don't find "import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;" exists?

Comment: show you dependencies from `pom.xml`

Comment: Hi @AlexeyR., it is too long for comment here, but I have pasted it in my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914497/maven-dont-run-tests . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please import **Afterall** hook from **cucumber** lib, **currently** you have imported the afterall annotation **from junit**. that is why Afterall is not executed.

[image]

These are the statements,

```
import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeStep;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
```

Comment: Sorry @Jayanth, but I don't get what the import should be, I don't find "import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;" if you are referring to it.

Comment: added above, please use that. and please do terminal -> "mvn clean install"

Comment: Thank you, but it says, it could not symbol after all. Maybe I am missing a dependency, but maven could not find the right one.

Comment: please remove junit import and re install maven => mvn clean install

Comment: Yes, I've removed it, but still got the message, that it could not find symbol.

Comment: Any idea @Jayanth Bala what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove junit dependency